# Who made the Elder Wand?

Tags: harry-potter, deathly-hallows

In The Tale of the Three Brothers, Death is said to have made the Elder Wand. Even Harry, who was accustomed to magic, found that idea ludicrous. Obviously, Death could not have made it... then who did?

Comment: I closed your question as a duplicate because the linked post includes the question of who made the Deathly Hallows: *By the way who created the deathly Hallows **actually**?*

Answer (score 1):

Antioch Peverell  was the first owner. Dumbledore’s theory was that he invended the Elder Wand, but in the fable it was a gift from death itself. I don’t think there’s a definitive answer.